# Accessing function variables with inline assembler

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I am using the **Diab** C compiler (v5.3.1.0) for the PowerPC and need to copy the MSR to a function's local variable.  Diab does not support GCC style C expression expansion so "mfmsr %0\n" : "=r" (msr) does not work.  Simply referencing the variable (mfmsr msr) does not work either.  The documentation is mostly silent on accessing C variables though it does say inline assembly is good for working with static variables but doesn't give an example.

Any advice or examples?

Answer (score 3):

Staring at the documentation finally lead me to the asm macro.  I created an assembler macro that looks a lot like a C function and call that.

```
__asm INT32U getMSR ()
{
   ! "r3"  /* Scratch register.*/

   mfmsr    r3
}
```

and where I want to get the MSR:

```
{
...
msr = getMSR ();
...
}
```

Comment: it may give MISRA warning since there is no return.